# Excel UDF calculation should return 'original' value

Tags: excel, vba, function, user-defined-functions

I have created a VSTO plugin with my own RTD implementation that I am calling from my Excel sheets. To avoid having to use the full-fledged RTD syntax in the cells, I have created a UDF that hides that API from the sheet.
The RTD server I created can be enabled and disabled through a button in a custom Ribbon component.

The behavior I want to achieve is as follows:

- If the server is **disabled** and a reference to my function is entered in a cell, I want the cell to display `Disabled`.
- If the server is **disabled**, but the function had been entered in a cell when it was enabled (and the cell thus displays a value), I want the cell to keep displaying that value.
- If the server is **enabled**, I want the cell to display `Loading`.

Sounds easy enough. Here is an example of the - non functional - code:

```
Public Function RetrieveData(id as Long)
  Dim result as String

  // This returns either 'Disabled' or 'Loading'
  result = Application.Worksheet.Function.RTD("SERVERNAME", "", id)
  RetrieveData = result

  If(result = "Disabled") Then

    // Obviously, this recurses (and fails), so that's not an option
    If(Not IsEmpty(Application.Caller.Value2)) Then

      // So does this
      RetrieveData = Application.Caller.Value2

    End If
  End If
End Function
```

The function will be called in thousands of cells, so storing the 'original' values in another data structure would be a major overhead and I would like to avoid it. Also, the RTD server does not know the values, since it also does not keep a history of it, more or less for the same reason.

I was thinking that there might be some way to exit the function which would force it to not change the displayed value, but so far I have been unable to find anything like that.

**EDIT:**
Due to popular demand, some additional info on why I want to do all this:
As I said, the function will be called in thousands of cells and the RTD server needs to retrieve quite a bit of information. This can be quite hard on both network and CPU. To allow the user to decide for himself whether he wants this load on his machine, they can disable the updates from the server. In that case, they should still be able to calculate the sheets with the values currently in the fields, yet no updates are pushed into them. Once new data is required, the server can be enabled and the fields will be updated.

Again, since we are talking about quite a bit of data here, I would rather not store it somewhere in the sheet. Plus, the data should be usable even if the workbook is closed and loaded again.

Comment: Someone else will have to provide a real answer about an alternate design using Excel, but there is no way to get a UDF to leave a cell alone once it's been triggered, and there is no way for a UDF to know the "previous" value of the cell it was called from (without storing it somewhere else *before* calculation is triggered). That's just fundamental to how spreadsheets work.

Comment: @jtolle That's a pity though: assume you want to count iterations of calculations in a cell. To do that, you always need a second data structure or another cell to keep track of the counter. In my opinion, that is a design flaw in Excel...

Comment: Why not pull your 'retrieveData' stuff out of a UDF and into a regular macro? Then you can overwrite cells or not depending on whatever logic you want. You can still have formulas that point to these cells and *those* can recalculate whenever the retrieved data (or any other inputs) change, in the normal spreadsheet manner.

Comment: I was thinking about that, too, but I really want the users to be able to use a function - it just makes more sense from an API perspective and the possibility for them to do something wrong is much smaller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different tack=new answer.

A few things I've discovered the hard way, that you might find useful:

**1.**
In a UDF, returning the RTD call like this

```
' excel equivalent: =RTD("GeodesiX.RTD",,"status","Tokyo")
result = excel.WorksheetFunction.rtd( _
    "GeodesiX.RTD", _
    Nothing, _
    "geocode", _
    request, _
    location)
```

behaves as if you'd inserted the commented function in the cell, and NOT the value returned by the RTD. In other words, "result" is an object of type "RTD-function-call" and not the RTD's answer. Conversely, doing this:

```
' excel equivalent: =RTD("GeodesiX.RTD",,"status","Tokyo")
result = excel.WorksheetFunction.rtd( _
    "GeodesiX.RTD", _
    Nothing, _
    "geocode", _
    request, _
    location).ToDouble ' or ToString or whetever
```

returns the actual value, equivalent to typing "3.1418" in the cell. This is an important difference; in the first case the cell continues to participate in RTD feeding, in the second case it just gets a constant value. This might be a solution for you.

**2.**
MS VSTO makes it look as though writing an Office Addin is a piece of cake... until you actually try to build an industrial, distributable solution. Getting all the privileges and authorities right for a Setup is a nightmare, and it gets exponentially worse if you have the bright idea of supporting more than one version of Excel. I've been using [Addin Express](http://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/) for some years. It hides all this MS nastiness and let's me focus on coding my addin. Their support is first-rate too, worth a look. (No, I am not affiliated or anything like that).

**3.**
Be aware that Excel can and will call Connect / RefreshData / RTD at any time, even when you're in the middle of something - there's some subtle multi-tasking going on behind the scenes. You'll need to decorate your code with the appropriate Synclock blocks to protect your data structures.

**4.**
When you receive data (presumably asynchronously on a separate thread) you **absolutely MUST** callback Excel on the thread on which you were intially called (by Excel). If you don't, it'll work fine for a while and then you'll start getting mysterious, unsolvable crashes and worse, orphan Excels in the background. Here's an example of the relevant code to do this:

```
    Imports System.Threading
    ...
    Private _Context As SynchronizationContext = Nothing
    ...
    Sub New
      _Context = SynchronizationContext.Current
      If _Context Is Nothing Then
         _Context = New SynchronizationContext ' try valiantly to continue    
      End If
    ...
    Private Delegate Sub CallBackDelegate(ByVal GeodesicCompleted)

    Private Sub GeodesicComplete(ByVal query As Query) _
        Handles geodesic.Completed ' Called by asynchronous thread

        Dim cbd As New CallBackDelegate(AddressOf GeodesicCompleted)

        _Context.Post(Function() cbd.DynamicInvoke(query), Nothing)
    End Sub
    Private Sub GeodesicCompleted(ByVal query As Query)

        SyncLock query

            If query.Status = "OK" Then

                Select Case query.Type

                    Case Geodesics.Query.QueryType.Directions
                        GeodesicCompletedTravel(query)

                    Case Geodesics.Query.QueryType.Geocode
                        GeodesicCompletedGeocode(query)

                End Select
            End If

            ' If it's not resolved, it stays "queued", 
            ' so as never to enter the queue again in this session
            query.Queued = Not query.Resolved

        End SyncLock

        For Each topic As AddinExpress.RTD.ADXRTDTopic In query.Topics
            AddinExpress.RTD.ADXRTDServerModule.CurrentInstance.UpdateTopic(topic)
        Next

    End Sub
```

**5.**
I've done something apparently akin to what you're asking in [this addin](http://www.calvert.ch/geodesix). There, I asynchronously fetch geocode data from Google and serve it up with an RTD shadowed by a UDF. As the call to GoogleMaps is very expensive, I tried 101 ways and several month's of evenings to keep the value in the cell, like what you're attempting, without success. I haven't timed anything, but my gut feeling is that a call to Excel like "Application.Caller.Value" is an order of magnitude slower than a dictionary lookup.

In the end I created a cache component which saves and re-loads values already obtained from a very-hidden spreadsheet which I create on the fly in Workbook OnSave. The data is stored in a Dictionary(of string, myQuery), where each myQuery holds all the relevant info.

It works well, fulfils the requirement for working offline and even for 20'000+ formulas it appears instantaneous.

HTH.

---

Edit: Out of curiosity, I tested my hunch that calling Excel is much more expensive than doing a dictionary lookup. It turns out that not only was the hunch correct, but frighteningly so.

```
Public Sub TimeTest()
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim val As Object
    Dim sheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)

    Const iterations As Integer = 100000
    Const elements As Integer = 10000

    For i = 1 To elements + 1
        dict.Add(i, i)
    Next
    sheet = _ExcelWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    sw.Reset()
    sw.Start()
    For i As Integer = 1 To iterations
        row = 1 + Rnd() * elements
    Next
    sw.Stop()
    Debug.WriteLine("Empty loop     " & (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds * 1000) / iterations & " uS")

    sw.Reset()
    sw.Start()
    For i As Integer = 1 To iterations
        row = 1 + Rnd() * elements
        val = sheet.Cells(row, 1).value
    Next
    sw.Stop()
    Debug.WriteLine("Get cell value " & (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds * 1000) / iterations & " uS")

    sw.Reset()
    sw.Start()
    For i As Integer = 1 To iterations
        row = 1 + Rnd() * elements
        val = dict(row)
    Next
    sw.Stop()
    Debug.WriteLine("Get dict value " & (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds * 1000) / iterations & " uS")

End Sub
```

Results:

```
Empty loop     0.07 uS
Get cell value 899.77 uS
Get dict value 0.15 uS
```

Looking up a value in a 10'000 element Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer) is **over 11'000 times faster** than fetching a cell value from Excel.

Q.E.D.

Comment: The 11000 factor is caused by using Interop. If you use COM VBA the factor is about 5 and for an XLL it would be even lower. But Dictionary is hard to beat.

Comment: @charles interesting remark, thanks. How would I go about using COM VBA from a .NET project?

Comment: @smirkingman This is by far one of the most extensive answers to a question I have received - thank you very much for taking the time and energy to share your knowledge. I've been trying different approaches last week and I ended up with pretty much the same architecture as you are proposing: I wrote a simple cache. It's not the most optimal solution, but so far it works and does not consume too much memory. Again, thanks a lot: I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @LeChe You're welcome, glad to have been of assistance. I will shortly be open-sourcing my geodesix addin along with documentation. If you're interested, drop me a line MAURICE at CALVERT dot CH

Comment: @smirkingman Unfortunately the only efficient way of interfacing .NET with Excel is via the XLL interface. You can do this with Addin Express, Excel DNA or managed XLL. Otherwise (sadly) its much more efficient to use VBA than .Net: hopefully this will change some time.

Comment: @Charles Ah, I see what you mean. I **am** using an Addin Express XLL as it happens; Excel calls XLLs reasonably fast, but if the XLL wants to get something from Excel (a cell value or whatever), Interop is the only possibility, thus the ghastly performance. Given that  it is not possible (or efficient or desirable) to write an asynchronous worker in VBA, we're indeed stuck with Interop.

Comment: If you are using an Addin Express XLL you can get data from an Excel cell via the XLL interface without going through Interop. I no longer have Addin express installed but my benchmark results are here http://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=5&TID=5586&MID=27780#message27780

Comment: @Charles In my opinion the "XLL interface" is nothing more than shorthand, the data has to be marshalled from managed to unmanaged and back, no matter what and this is where we get the performance hit. Thus the consensus we're arriving at: local caching in managed code is always going to be significantly faster.

Comment: @smirkingman - I agree that using the Dictionary approach is fastest in this case. But for data transfer between Excel and code the XLL interface (C API) is significantly faster than interop-Com. So for performing UDFs etc XLL is the technology to choose, even if using .Net. But even XLL .NET is still slower than VB6-COM because of the managed-unmanaged transition (and much slower than C++ XLL)

Comment: @charles Forgive me if I'm being dreadfully thick here, but in a vb.net app, what are you referring to when you say "XLL.Net" (as opposed to "sheet.Cells(row, 1).value", or the "vArr(j, k)" example you mentioned on ADX)? Could you give an example piece of code? Thanks! Oh, and @LeChe, sorry for polluting your thread...

Comment: The open-source code I alluded to back in 2011 is available here http://www.calvert.ch/geodesix/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe... Try making your UDF wrapper function non-volatile, that way it won't get called unless one of its arguments changes.

This might be a problem when you enable the server, you'll have to trick Excel into calling your UDF again, it depends on what you're trying to do.

Perhaps explain the complete function you're trying to implement?

Comment: Thanks for the great pointer, I will have a look at non-volatile functions. As a matter of fact, I only want the calculation to happen if one of the parameters change anyway. Plus, I hope an active RTD server will still trigger cell updates, even if the function that called RTD is non-volatile. By the way, what I described above IS the complete function - there is really no magic involved, it's simply a wrapper for my RTD call (plus the little extra thingy I am struggling with :). Anyway, I'll add some more details to the question on why I want to do all of this...

Comment: Turns out you cannot mark a function non-volatile, only volatile. So by default, they are non-volatile. Bummer, seems like this is not the way to go... :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try Application.Caller.Text
 This has the drawback of returning the formatted value from the rendering layer as text, but seems to avoid the circular reference problem.
Note: I have not tested this hack under all possible circumstances ...

Comment: You beat me to it. :) I was playing around with the .Text property, too. Yet as you say: it returns the formatted value, which is not really the value. Plus - especially in a financial environment - this can introduce pretty bad errors. But thanks a lot for the input, it seems to be indeed the only option.